# How to deserialise complex JSON with JSON.net c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have JSON with Dictionary of string-key with value-arrays. There are his structure below:

```
{
"NameA":{
    "ParametersA":[
        [104.3,5.368783],
        [104.212,2.57357],...,
    ],
    "ParametersB":[
        [104.3,5.368783],
        [104.212,2.57357],...,
    ]
},
"NameB":{
    "ParametersA":[
        [104.3,5.368783],
        [104.212,2.57357],...,
    ],
    "ParametersB":[
        [104.3,5.368783],
        [104.212,2.57357],...,
        ]
    },
"ThousandsNamesN":{[...]
    }
}
```

I create class for this to obtain data like this: `Dictionaty<key=NameA, value=List<Parameters>>` and parameters is another class with to arrays A and B.

This is my Root class:

```
    internal class RawDepth
{
    public Dictionary<string, Parameters> Names { get; set; }

    internal class Parameters
    {
        [JsonProperty("ParametersA")]
        public IList<Orders> A { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("ParametersB")]
        public IList<ParamsArray> B { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ParamsArray
    {
        public decimal[,] _Orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I catchs a null reference exception. I tried create class different ways, but I still can't deserialise it. What I doing wrong?

Comment: Seperate your classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model can be simply something like this

```
public class Parameters
{
    public List<List<decimal>> ParametersA { get; set; }
    public List<List<decimal>> ParametersB { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize as

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Parameters>>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tool [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/#) that lets you paste JSON and it generates C# classes from it. That's what I got from your sample:

```
public class NameA
{
    public List<List<double>> ParametersA { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ParametersB { get; set; }
}

public class NameB
{
    public List<List<double>> ParametersA { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ParametersB { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public NameA NameA { get; set; }
    public NameB NameB { get; set; }
    public List<string> ThousandsNamesN { get; set; }
}
```

I think we can safely assume that NameA and NameB classes are the same.

I had to edit JSON a little fot it to work, so I will paste it below:

```
    {
"NameA":{
    "ParametersA":[
        [104.3,5.368783],
        [104.212,2.57357],
    ],
    "ParametersB":[
        [104.3,5.368783],
        [104.212,2.57357],
    ]
},
"NameB":{
    "ParametersA":[
        [104.3,5.368783],
        [104.212,2.57357],
    ],
    "ParametersB":[
        [104.3,5.368783],
        [104.212,2.57357],
        ]
    },
"ThousandsNamesN":["name1", "name2"]

}
```

So after taking into consideration what was your initail idea, your code should look like that:

```
public class Order
{
    public List<List<double>> ParametersA { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> ParametersB { get; set; }
}

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Order>>(json);
```

Comment: I know, use the same service. But I have Thousands keys NameA, NameB, ...NameN where N can be 3000-4000. Early I deserialise same JSON to Dictionary where NameA..N was in another object, but in this JSON i have troubles...

Comment: I've edited my answer. You root object is a dictionary